# Change ToggleButton background to Clear/Dark Gray

Tags: android

I'm using two toggle buttons on my application, when I run it on the emulator the button has black text, and a light gray background. As we can see in the next image:

[image: Clear ToggleButton]

When I run it on my real device the button has another style, it has white text, and a black background. As shown in the next image.

[image: Dark ToggleButton]

My QUESTION IS: How to change the style of a ToggleButton to it always stay with a clear gray background, as in the first image? Is it defined by a Theme?

The xml code used for the button was:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButtonSimulado"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:textOff="Off" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Style of the button or any other view changes in the real device according to the current theme selected on that device. To prevent this you need to specify background color and text color explicitly. Use a gradient as the background of the button. For example:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleButtonSimulado"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gray_gradient"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this way I will need to create the drawable/gray_gradient. Is there any way to do this with out creating my own background? Does android has any available backgrounds to use?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes the answer is no. You can use a small  9 patch image as background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own backgrounds for the buttons.
Search btn_toggle_off.9.png/btn_toggle_on.9 on your sdk install dir(android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-9/data/res/drawable-hdpi).
And make sure to copy the selector located on drawable folder

Or you can try:

[androiddrawables](http://androiddrawables.com/)

[androiddrawablesexplorer](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood, and probably this will work, but it it's forcing. Why I need to copy files from android SDK to my app folder? Should have a way to solve that without copy the buttons components to my folder. A style or theme maybe.

Comment: I try to achieve the same with themes, using a custom one on the application tag in the manifest, but only the ProgressBar widget take the new theme drawable :(